# Proving a function converges to 0 when we know something about its generalized integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

$f(x)$ is continuously differentiable in $[a, +\infty)$, if $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_a^{\infty}f'(x)dx$ converge, try to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$.

I have proved a related lemma as follows:

$f(x)$ is generalized Riemann integrable in $[a, +\infty)$, if $f(x)$ is differentiable in $[a, +\infty)$ and $f'(x)$ is bounded, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$.

I'm not sure whether the lemma is useful in proving the original propositon, please show me some valid proof or hints. If you don't understand my question, let me know ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that$$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf'(t)\,\mathrm d t.$$

Since $\int_a^\infty f'(x)\,\mathrm d x,$ converges, then $$\ell:=\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x),$$
exist. Suppose that $\ell\neq 0$. Suppose $\ell>0$. Let $M\geq a$ s.t. $f(x)\geq \frac{\ell}{2}.$ In particular, if $x>M$, then $$\int_a^x f(x)\mathrm d x=\int_a^Mf(x)\,\mathrm d x+\int_M^x f(x)\,\mathrm d x\geq \int_a^M f(x)\,\mathrm d x+\frac{(x-M)\ell}{2}\underset{x\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }\infty ,$$
which is a contradiction. Do the same if $\ell<0$ and conclude.

Comment: It seems should be $\dfrac{l(x-M)}{2}$ instead of $\dfrac{lx}{2}$, but thaks a lot anyway.

Comment: Yes, you right. I edited. @user823011